# R: How to customize plotly interactive hover window?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, tidyverse, data-visualization

Here I have interactive barplot given by ggplotly. The only issue is that when I move mouse around bars, in the "model" category there is strange number instead of A or B (see the picture). Is it possible to customize plotly popup windows?

```
   df <- data.frame (model  = c("A", "A","B","B"),
                      year = c("2022","2021","2022","2021"),
                      sale = c(350,170,300,150),
                      change = c(180,NA,150,NA),
                      percent = c(105.8,NA,100,NA),
                      info = c("180, 105.8%",NA,"300,100%",NA)
                      )




#ggplot
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(fill=year, y=model, x=sale)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + geom_text(aes(label=info, x=1.11*max(sale),), fontface='bold')+ xlim(0, 1.2*max(df$sale)) +
 theme(legend.position="bottom")+labs(fill = " ")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired")



ggplotly(plot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, it works better if you use `x=model` and flip the axes:

```
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(fill=year, x=model, y=sale)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + geom_text(aes(label=info,y=1.11*max(sale),), fontface='bold')+
  ylim(0, 1.2*max(df$sale)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+labs(fill = " ")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired")+
  coord_flip()

ggplotly(plot)
```

[image]

Comment: and what is the raason?

Comment: Didn't dive into `plotly' internals to find out ;-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72476380/r-how-to-customize-hover-window-in-plotly

Answer (score 1):

Personally, i avoid using `ggplotly()` as it more often than not formats the visuals in a way that i do not want.

A full `plotly` approach could look like this:

```
plot_ly(
  data = df,
  x = ~sale,
  y = ~model,
  color = ~year,
  text = ~year,
  type = "bar") %>% 
  add_trace(
    x = ~max(df$sale) * 1.1,
    y = ~model,
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'text',
    text = ~info,
    showlegend = FALSE
  ) %>% 
  style(hovertemplate = paste("Sale: %{x}",
                              "Model: %{y}",
                              "Year: %{text}",
                              sep = "<br>"))
```

[image]

You could also try to append the `style()` object to your `ggplotly()` object. I am not sure if this will work however.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72476380/r-how-to-customize-hover-window-in-plotly